# aligning the two buttons on the center of screen using padding

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons in my code and wondering how can I move them to the center of the screen using CSS.I tried playing around with the       `padding: 10px 24px 24px 30px;` but it doesn't seem to be putting the two buttons at the center of the screen. Also, I want them to be responsive.

Here is my snippet:

```css
/* .btn-group button {   */
    .btn-group-vertical button { 
      background-color: #0b0e0d; /* Black background */
      border: 1px solid rgb(239, 240, 239); /*  border */
      color: white; /* White text */
      padding: 10px 24px 24px 30px; /* Some padding top right bottom left */
      cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
      width: 50%; /* Set a width if needed */
      display: block; /* Make the buttons appear below each other */
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 14px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    
    .btn-group button:not(:last-child) {   
      border-bottom: none; /* Prevent double borders */
    }
    
    /* Add a background color on hover */
    /* .btn-group button:hover { */
    .btn-group-vertical button:hover {    
      background-color: #ffffff; 
      color: #0b6d11;
    }
```

```html
<div  >
        <div >
            <div class="btn-group-vertical"> 
                    <button type="button" id = "stbButton " '">First Button</button>
                    <button type="button" id = "cdbButton"  >Second Button</button>
             </div> 
         </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:flex` in your container, then align and justify your elements to the centre. Setting `flex-container` to `column` will stack your elements on top of each other.

Setting the height to `100vh` will make the container fill the height of the viewport, and your content will be vertically centred within it:

```css
.btn-group-vertical {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:100vh;
}


/* .btn-group button {   */

.btn-group-vertical button {
  background-color: #0b0e0d;
  /* Black background */
  border: 1px solid rgb(239, 240, 239);
  /*  border */
  color: white;
  /* White text */
  padding: 10px 24px 24px 30px;
  /* Some padding top right bottom left */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Pointer/hand icon */
  width: 50%;
  max-width:300px; /* set a maximum width if you fancy */
  /* Set a width if needed */
  display: block;
  /* Make the buttons appear below each other */
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: none;
  /* Prevent double borders */
}


/* Add a background color on hover */


/* .btn-group button:hover { */

.btn-group-vertical button:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #0b6d11;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group-vertical">
  <button type="button" id="stbButton">First Button</button>
  <button type="button" id="cdbButton">Second Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add margin: auto to the btn-group-vertical class. It will get positioned in the center and be responsive as well.

Comment: Thanks.That is putting at the center and top.  How to put both the buttons at the center of the screen? Also, that seems to be disturbing `margin-botton:50px`